# Images served via http won't display on https website in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

This has only started happening as of this morning.  I have a wordpress website served via https, and all of the images on the site served via http aren't appearing all of a sudden.  This only appears to be happening on Chrome (47.0.2526.73 m) and Firefox (41.0.1) however it appears to work on IE, and mobile safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called Mixed Content (Mixed Protocol),When the webpage is loaded over SSL (HTTPS protocol), most browsers expect all of the assets to be loaded over the same protocol. Some browsers will display an error about loading “insecure content” while others will just block the insecure content outright.
for fix that in wordpress  there are two solutions that you can see [here](http://ithemes.com/codex/page/Fix_Non-SSL_Elements_on_SSL_Page)